# $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{2^{2n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, contour-integration

I want to examine the convergence of the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{2^{2n}}$$

In case it converges I want to evaluate it.

I tried the D' Alembert theorem but it was inconclusive.I have a feeling it converges but  with the use of complex analysis I get :

I used the known fact that $\displaystyle 2\pi i\binom{2n}{n}=\oint_{\gamma}\frac{\left ( 1+z \right )^{2n}}{z^{n+1}}\,{\rm d}z$ whereas $\gamma$ is any closed circle around the origin  and then I proceeded as follows:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left ( 1+z \right )^{2n}}{z^{n+1}}\frac{1}{2^{2n}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z}\left ( \frac{(1+z)^2}{4z} \right )^n=\cdots=-\frac{4}{\left ( z-1 \right )^2}$$

because it is a geometric series. Problem is that I cannot apply contour integration around the unit circle because $1$ in on the circle not inside.

So, this leads me to believe that the series divirges as W|A gives me. But I cannot prove that either since the ratio test is incoclusive. So the best approach would be by the comparison test. But compare it to what series? I cannot see an obvious one. In case it converges , around which circle should I apply contour integration to finish things off?

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Comment: Let $~S(a)~=~\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty{2n\choose n}^ax^n.\quad$ Then $$S(0)=\dfrac1{1-x}~,\quad S(1)=\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-4x}}~,\quad S(2)=\dfrac2\pi K\big(4\sqrt x\big)~,\quad S(3)=\bigg[\dfrac2\pi K\Big(\sqrt y\Big)\bigg]^2,$$ where $~y=\dfrac{1-\sqrt{1-64x}}2~$ and $~K~$ is the [elliptic integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Stirling's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

$$\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\sim\frac{(2n)^{2n}e^{-2n}\sqrt{4\pi n}}{n^{2n}e^{-2n}2\pi n}\frac{1}{2^{2n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$$

Comment: So, it divirges!!

Comment: @Tolaso Yes, that seems to be the case.

Comment: Note that $\sum \binom{2n}{n}x^n$ converges for $|x| < \frac12$.

Comment: @martycohen Note that that doesn't give information about $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @martycohen If this is the case then in our situation this should converge, because $x=1/4$. No?

Comment: @Tolaso He probably forgot a $2$ in the exponent of the $x$ or computed the radius wrong.

Comment: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2 n}{n} x^{2 n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4 x^2}}$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Maybe!! Anyway, thank you all for your answers...

Comment: Once again, my lack of perfection has been revealed for all to see. Oh, woe is me!

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is by using **[Raabe's Theorem](https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDMQFjAC&url=%68%74%74%70%3A%2F%2F%6D%61%74%68%77%6F%72%6C%64%2E%77%6F%6C%66%72%61%6D%2E%63%6F%6D%2F%52%61%61%62%65%73%54%65%73%74%2E%68%74%6D%6C&ei=D0rgVNfDGuHSmAXx2IKgAw&usg=AFQjCNE9hYTms94vR5MsDWH6tC7lO1Lc8Q&sig2=d-SqmjIXjKILx4Zs-LygkA)** for a positive series.
Let
$$\lambda(n)=n(\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}-1)=\frac{n}{2n+1}$$
Since
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\lambda(n)=\frac12<1$$
According to Raabe's Theorem, the series diverges.